# How to find out what is causing decreased performance when USB-C power delivery is plugged in on a laptop running linux

Tags: usb, performance, power-management

I searched around and could not find an answer to this issue.

For context: I am running ArchLinux on my Tuxedo InfinityBook 14 gen7 with RTX 3050 TI, the regular power adapter that came with the laptop is rated for 90W. The proprietary NVidia drivers are installed and it is running Gnome on Wayland.

When I use my laptop on battery power it runs smoothly and I can even play games at full speed.

The issue I am having is when I connect it to a USB-C power delivery. It instantly slows down. If I plug in the regular power adapter instead it works fine.

Does anyone knows what could be the issue? I tried many USB-C power supplies, for instance I tried some 65W, 100W, 130W and 140W adapters, with many different cables as well, rated 100W and more.

Something is making the CPU / GPU throttle when I plug in the USB-C power and I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Arch allows for so many different configurations and combinations of packages and settings that this question is almost impossible to answer unless you add more info. Also: Have you checked the arch wiki?

Comment: Yes, I checked the wiki and there is nothing that could explain this behavior there either. My setup is probably the most standard Arch install, just base, base-devel, gnome, gnome-extra and so on. I guess I will have to live with carrying 2 power supplies, the standard one and the usb-c for phone, and other stuff. My hope was to be able to leave the standard adapter at home when I travel but seems that won't be possible.

Comment: My guess would be that the USB-C is not giving you enough power.  The bug can be either in firmware or HW.   The powerdesign of USB PD is for 100W so that should be sufficient.  However, the manufacturer can either enforce some kind of limit or have a bug which will cause the such behaviour.

Comment: Seems known bug: https://www.reddit.com/r/tuxedocomputers/comments/zl9xdc/infinitybook_pro_14_gen_7_usbc_charging_and/

Comment: Ooops. "Due to the current limitation of the Power Delivery DC-In standard to 100 watts (Extended Power Range, EPR for short, with up to 240 watts is still hardly widespread), full laptop performance cannot always be accessed as described above. The operation via USB-C charger is only recommended with deactivated NVIDIA graphics. This can be easily done via the TUXEDO Control Center (click on the taskbar icon » Graphics » Select built-in) or via the UEFI/BIOS firmware." https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Charging-via-USB-C-power-supply-Power-Delivery-DC-In.tuxedo

Comment: May I found it. https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Charging-via-USB-C-power-supply-Power-Delivery-DC-In.tuxedo 
The default USB-C charging option: "Priorize battery charging speed" Change it to "Priorize performance " in the Tuxedo Control Center.